# Will a smaller postgres amazon RDS replica throttle a larger one when bulk writing?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In AWS RDS, If I have a large instance for my master and a significantly smaller replica what will happen when writing large amounts of data. Here are some hypotheses I have:

A) The larger master instance is throttled trying to keep the two instances in sync and writes will be as fast as I could write to the the same instane as the replica

B) The larger master instance can ingest data much quicker than the smaller replica. The larger instance will have data available first while the smaller replica lags behind until all data is in sync with master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is what is called "synchronous replication" and the second "asynchronous". So, it depends on how replication is configured. I believe AWS supports both.

Comment: Looks like read replicas for RDS are asynchronous. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.html.

Comment: They do have an option somewhere though. Ah - this I think https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html

Comment: @RichardHuxton the synchronous option is called Multi-AZ.  In this configuration, both the active and standby instances are always identical machines, and the standby instance is not accessible, so can't be used for reads... so it's really not a replica in the sense used in the question.